# Найти разницу между perfect square и сравнить с входным значением

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const findSquares = num => {

  for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    const valueArray = Math.pow(i, 2)

    const nextValueArray = valueArray + num

    if(nextValueArray - valueArray === num) {
      return `${nextValueArray} - ${valueArray}`
    }
  }
}
```

На выходе должно быть 25-16. Пробовал прибавлять к текущему значения квадрата получаемое число и потом делать проверку на разницу двух квадратов, но не выходит. Максимум что делает это получает входное значение из первых любых значений квадрата

Comment: Три раза прочитал код и текст. Так и не понял что же нужно. Код вообще бессмысленный,  зачем-то вычисляет сотню квадратов и ничего с ними не делает.

Comment: А теперь то что на скриншоте добавьте буквами

Comment: Добавил то что на скриншоте буквами

Comment: `const nextValueArray = valueArray + num

    if(nextValueArray - valueArray === num)` — какой сложный способ написать `if (true)`

Comment: Ну и всё ещё непонятно что же мы пытаемся найти? Покажите больше примеров.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, не обязательно `true`, если например `num` будет строкой :)

Comment: Уже решил самостоятельно, но также есть решение ниже которое все объясняет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, что делает этот код - возводит числа в квадрат.

А что он должен делать - из описания пока непонятно. Может быть, нужно сделать два вложенных цикла, и смотреть разницу между получаемыми квадратами?

```
    for(let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
       let sqi = i * i;
       for(let j = i + 1; j < 100; j++) {
          let sqj = j * j;
          if (sqi - sqj == num)
              чего-то делать
       }   
    }
```

После того, как дано условие задачи - оказывается, там два соседних квадрата нужно смотреть

```
const findSquares = num => {
  for(let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     let sqi = i * i;
     let sqj = (i + 1)*(i + 1)
     if (sqj - sqi == num) {
           return `${sqj}-${sqi}`;
      }   
   }
};
```

Однако решение можно получить и без перебора - достаточно посмотреть в школьном учебнике, чему равна разность двух соседних квадратов. Поскольку гарантировано, что входное нечётное, то весь код вот:

```
const findSquares = num => {
  let i = (num - 1) / 2;
  return `${(i+1)*(i+1)}-${i*i}`;
};
```

или

```
  return `${(i*i + num}-${i*i}`;
```

Comment: как я понял, разница между квадратами должна давать число из которого извлекается целочисленный корень

Comment: @NMD Ну я тоже понял так, что ищутся пифагоровы тройки, но автору стоит получше формулировать.

Comment: Он должен возвращать строку, разницей которого является входное число. Типо "25-16" А входное число в функцию 9

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/60908bc1d5811f0025474291/train/javascript

Comment: Вот ссылка на задачу

Comment: Это уже сами сообразите, как сделать, основу для нахождения этих чисел я написал

Comment: вот сразу надо было писать более детально, что нужно. правильно заданный вопрос 99% ответа

Comment: я выложил пример кода и что должно получаться, то что у вас вообще не работает

Comment: @24hrs Ну теперь-то проверили?

Comment: @MBo решил самостоятельно

Comment: Отлично. Надеюсь, не тот код прошёл, который сейчас в вопросе

Comment: @MBo Да, он. Просто следующее NextValue по другому нашёл :)

Comment: @MBo написал nextValue = (Math.pow(i + 1, 2)

Comment: ОК. Только этот код не пройдёт (ATTEMPT,а не TEST)  для больших чисел. Или нужно 100 менять на гораздо большее, или использовать более оптимальный подход  - то, что у меня в конце

Comment: @MBo да, вы правы. Я изменил 100 на большее, что указано в задаче. И все прошло. Но ваш вариант проще и лучше. Поэтому посоветуйте пожалуйста, что у вас за учебник по математике?

Comment: Да это просто формула (i+1)^2 = i^2 + 2*i + 1 - т.е. различие соседних двух квадратов  2*i + 1, поэтому мы можем получить i из num как let i = (num - 1) / 2;

Comment: @MBo Спасибо за объяснение